# Handling exception before the assigning of a scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, exception, boost, smart-pointers

A member of my class is a `boost::scoped_ptr` which is set to `(T*)0` when the object is created. The class has an `init()` method that actually initializes the smart pointer with a new object.

However, if an exception is thrown *before* that smart pointer has a valid reference, it very un-smartly tries to delete null (release) or it asserts (debug).

**How do I get it to ignore null pointers upon destruction without modifying the original source code; and, if that isn't possible, is there a more suitable alternate smart pointer class to use instead?**

Comment: I suspect that something else is wrong with your code. `delete 0` is perfectly valid (and does nothing). Please add a minimal test case which reproduces the problem.

Comment: So objects of this type are not working in the presence of exceptions before `init` is called? What about then just trasnforming the `init` into a constructor to not even have such invalid objects? Other than that *Mankarse* is right that `delete 0` is nothing bad, and it isn't that unsmart in itself (in fact it's smarter than doing a manual check beforehand), and doesn't really cost anything.

Comment: @ChristianRau - See my comment under mauve's answer. It was the logic in my code. I was a bad programmer and didn't step through the code before posting this :] I did a few test cases and yes, Mankarse is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost::scoped_ptr actually ignores null pointers in its destructor. boost::scoped_ptr uses boost::checked_delete() for deletion. boost::checked_delete() uses plain `delete` in order to delete (boost::checked_delete() also checks so that T is not incomplete).

And you are allowed to delete null pointers with delete (unlike `free()`). Are you sure that the error is really in boost::scoped_ptr ?

Comment: It wasn't. It was my code's logic (I really should have stepped through the code before posting this; thank you sleep deprivation). The scoped_ptr was keeping track of the console object, and the test exception was being thrown before the console object was being created/assigned to the smart pointer. The catch block was then using the console object to log the error, which at that point in time didn't yet exist, forming a null-pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `std::unique_ptr` instead of `boost::scoped_ptr` and provide a custom delete function that would check the state of the underlying object - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr.

Comment: My only gripe about unique_ptr is that it isn't c++0x compatible. If it really must come down to it I can use it, but I'd rather not have to in this case.

Comment: *"it isn't c++0x compatible"* - You mean C++03/98, since it is pretty well C++0x (or rather C++11) compatible.

Comment: Oh derp yes, got that backwards.